# Would HBase/HDFS deployment make sense with 100mbit/s network interfaces?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I guess that 100Mbit/s network interface will be bottle neck for HDFS and slow down HBase on top of it (max compactions speed about 10MB/s, etc.). Would this deployment make sense?

I am thinking that "now" when when SSD comes in to game even 1Gbit/s network interfeces still can be bottleneck, so maybe building a cluster with 100Mbit/s should never be taken into account (even for HDD)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not your network will be the bottleneck depends on the kinds of jobs you are running.  If you do text processing (e.g. running Stanford NER or coreference suite), then a 100Mbit/s network will be the least of your concerns.  However, if you are doing a lot of I/O intensive processing (most jobs with big reduce steps), then it will be.  As always, it depends on your workload.  But, I think it is safe to say that a 100Mb network is the most likely culprit for a bottleneck given recent processors and nodes with several disks.

Answer (score 2):

To keep it short:
You should **never** use a SSD in HDFS, these flash memorys have a limited number of writes. HDFS has many writes, that's mainly because of the replication. If you are using HBase as a NoSQL DB this will result in even more writes. 
The bottlenecks are as you said the harddisk and the network. Network is an even higher bottleneck because you are distributing the data, so it has to be replicated and if you are running jobs, they could be copied if the data is not locally available (Reducers have to copy much stuff). 
So you should definitely for a better network than 10Mbit or 100Mbit. That implies your switch and the NICs on the nodes. 
 
A hdd raid will not result in a higher bandwidth in writing, there were several benchmarks that proof that. Have a look at the HDFS Wiki, it must be described there.

Comment: While I agree that HBase adds a lot of writes (major and minor compactions), I am not sure what you refer to with "index columns"

Answer (score 2):

100MB network is not likely to be a good setup for an hadoop cluster you can see [cisco's presentation from Hadoop World](http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/hadoop-network-and-compute-architecture-considerations-jacob-rapp-cisco) for some analysis of network usage. That said depending on your actual load and cluster size it might be workable - though you might want to make sure you actually need Hadoop if that is the case.

regarding SSDs they cost more per MB and depending on your write load you may have to replace them sooner than HDDs but they will save you electricity  - I guess it wouldn't be cost effective to use them in a large cluster (I don't know of anyone who did)
You can use SSDs for some of the disks e.g. for the temporary space on the cluster (such as map/reduce  intermediate results) to get the IO benefits